# What is a suitable way of organising the structure of my game engine's rendering code in an API agnostic way?

Tags: c++, graphics, architecture, game-engine

I've tried a few different ways to abstract my game engine code in order to support various graphics APIs, but without much luck.

I currently have something like this:

```
class IPlatform
{
public:
    virtual void Initialise() = 0;
    virtual void Dispose() = 0;
    virtual void DrawTriangle();
    virtual void SwapBuffers();
    virtual void PollEvents();
};
```

With each platform/API having there own implementation like this:

```
// OpenGL Platform
class GlPlatform : public IPlatform
{
public:
    GlPlatform();
    virtual ~GlPlatform();

    void Initialise() override;
    void Dispose() override;
    void DrawTriangle() override;
    void SwapBuffers() override;
    void PollEvents() override;
};
```

I have a similar abstraction for the windowing systems. But my main confusion is how various APIs can be abstracted to work with different windowing systems and the order in which to initialise everything. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: are you actually writing a game that uses the engine and that makes use of different graphics APIs ? You need a test, some example to see if it makes sense. WIthout that it will stay abstract and you cannot know if it is of any use or needs tweaking

Comment: You might want to leverage [Halide](https://halide-lang.org/) instead of trying to do your own abstraction layer.